# Can't print whole string to text files from a csv file using bat file

Tags: batch-file, token

I'm trying to split a `.csv` file into `2` different text files dynamically based on the delimiter, `,`, using a `.bat` file.

What I am currently getting is `2` text files, but `1` of them is only picking up half of the string due to spaces between them.

Here is the output of the current `.csv`:

```
Sandbox,Daily 07:00
```

Current the 2 text files look like this:

```
1. Sandbox
```

```
2. Daily
```

Here is the output of the current bat file:

```
echo %DATE%
echo %TIME%
set datetimef=%date:~-4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (C:\_TEMP_\Tableau_Auto_Refresh\Tableau_Auto_Refresh_Trigger_File.csv) do (
    echo %%a  > C:\_TEMP_\Tableau_Auto_Refresh\Site.txt
    echo %%b  > C:\_TEMP_\Tableau_Auto_Refresh\Schedule.txt
)

TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
```

Comment: You're using spaces, _and parentheses_, as your defined delimiters; what do you expect to happen at those delimiters? You're also not using the third token, i.e. that attributed to `%%c`!

Comment: Does this look better then?

Comment: You're still using commas and spaces as your defined delimiters; your question states that you're delimiting on commas!

Comment: Got in working! This does the job now! Thank you :)

Comment: Can't replicate your problem. Your code seems to do, what you want (except perhaps using `>>` is better than `>` to append each line to the destination files)